# Implementation of std::map

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel

I have decided to make a basic C++ implementation of the `std::map` class, and I was checking that it is fine, as I am not sure if the `operator[]` is done correctly: should I be using the `has_key` function? e.t.c

```
template < typename _Key, typename _Ty, typename _Cmp = std::less<_Key>, typename _Alloc = std::allocator< std::pair<const _Key, _Ty> > > class map
{
public:
    typedef map<_Key, _Ty, _Cmp, _Alloc> _Myt;
    typedef _Key key_type;
    typedef _Ty mapped_type;
    typedef _Cmp compare_type;
    typedef _Alloc allocator_type;
    typedef std::pair<const key_type, mapped_type> value_type;
    typedef value_type *pointer;
    typedef const value_type *const_pointer;
    typedef value_type *iterator;
    typedef const value_type *const_iterator;
    typedef std::size_t size_type;
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;

    map()
        : size_(0), capacity_(20), data_(_Alloc().allocate(20))
    {
    }

    map(const _Myt &_Rhs)
        : size_(_Rhs.size_), capacity_(_Rhs.size_ + 20), data_(_Alloc().allocate(_Rhs.size_))
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (iterator i = &_Rhs.data_[0]; i != &_Rhs.data_[_Rhs.size_]; ++i, ++count)
        {
            _Alloc().construct(&data_[count], *i);
        }
    }

    ~map()
    {
        if (!empty())
        {
            for (iterator i = begin(); i != end(); ++i)
            {
                _Alloc().destroy(i);
            }
            _Alloc().deallocate(data_, capacity_);
        }
    }

    _Myt &insert(const value_type &_Value)
    {
        if (++size_ >= capacity_)
        {
            reserve(capacity_ * 2);
        }
        _Alloc().construct(&data_[size_ - 1], _Value);
        return *this;
    }

    bool has_key(const key_type &_Key)
    {
        for (iterator i = begin(); i != end(); ++i)
        {
            if (i->first == _Key)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    mapped_type &operator[](const key_type &_Key)
    {
        if (has_key(_Key))
        {
            for (iterator i = begin(); i != end(); ++i)
            {
                if (i->first == _Key)
                {
                    return i->second;
                }
            }
        }
        size_type op = size_;
        insert(value_type(_Key, mapped_type()));
        return data_[op].second;
    }

    _Myt &reserve(size_type _Capacity)
    {
        int count = 0;
        if (_Capacity < capacity_)
        {
            return *this;
        }
        pointer buf = _Alloc().allocate(_Capacity);
        for (iterator i = begin(); i != end(); ++i, ++count)
        {
            _Alloc().construct(&buf[count], *i);
        }
        std::swap(data_, buf);
        for (iterator i = &buf[0]; i != &buf[size_]; ++i)
        {
            _Alloc().destroy(i);
        }
        _Alloc().deallocate(buf, capacity_);
        capacity_ = _Capacity;
        return *this;
    }

    bool empty()
    {
        return size_ == 0;
    }

    iterator begin()
    {
        return &data_[0];
    }

    iterator end()
    {
        return &data_[size_];
    }
private:
    pointer data_;
    size_type size_, capacity_;
};
```

Comment: I am downvoting this for your use of reserved identifiers. You have been advised not to do this in all of your previous STL exercise that you put up here for review. Please STOP AND READ.

Comment: You also fail at some basic points of `std::map`:  it must not allow insertion of duplicates (which you only prevent in `operator[]`, but not in `.insert()`), and it must store its elements in key order (which you make no effort at).

Answer (score 10):

**Readability**

With your lengthy `template` statement, I'd put the `class` statement onto the next line:

```
template </*...*/>
class map
```

**Naming standards**

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797), identifiers in the form `_Identifier` are reserved:

> **7.1.3 Reserved identifiers**
>
> Each header declares or defines all identifiers listed in its
>   associated subclause, and optionally declares or defines identifiers
>   listed in its associated future library directions subclause and
>   identifiers which are always reserved either for any use or for use as
>   file scope identifiers.
>
> - All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase
>     letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use.
>
> [...]

**Const-correctness**

- You have iterators, but you should also have `const` iterators:

  ```
  const_iterator cbegin() const
  {
      return &data_[0];
  }

  const_iterator cend() const
  {
      return &data_[size_];
  }
  ```
- `empty()` should be `const`:

  ```
  bool empty() const
  {
      return size_ == 0;
  }
  ```
- `has_key()` should be `const` *and* use the aforementioned `const` iterators:

  ```
  bool has_key(const key_type &_Key) const
  {
      for (const_iterator i = cbegin(); i != cend(); ++i)
      {
          if (i->first == _Key)
          {
              return true;
          }
      }
      return false;
  }
  ```

Comment: Having `const_iterator begin() const;` is probably a higher priority than `cbegin()`, 'twas introduced first because it's the more useful, propagating `const` correctness in certain template situations.  The lack of `const` correctness obviously led to `for (iterator i = &_Rhs.data_[0]; i != &_Rhs.data_[_Rhs.size_]; ++i, ++count)` - that can be cleaned up as `...i = rhs.begin(); i != rhs.end();...`.

Answer (score 6):

> [...] I am not sure if the operator[] is done correctly: should I be using the has_key function?

It is done correctly (i.e. it does what the contract of its API should), but not efficiently. The operator iterates twice (once in `has_key` and once in the operator). You can replace both calls with a call to `std::find_if`, and remove the `has_key` function completely.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `std::vector` as internal container. It will simplify your code a lot.

I also would store the array sorted. This will slow down adding the keys, but search will be O(log(N)). Removing the data will be faster too.

I also would use "new" C++11 for:

```
bool has_key(const key_type &key) const
{
    for (auto const &x : *this )
        if (x.first == key)
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

Or if you can use C++17:

```
bool has_key(const key_type &key) const
{
    for (auto const [k, v] : *this )
        if (k == key)
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

You can also use `std::find` standard algorithm for this, but I personally would do it in C++11 way:

```
bool has_key(const key_type &key) const
{
    return std::find(cbegin(), cend(), key) != cend();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are searching two times the entire arrays to find your key,pair value. This is highly inefficient. Instead you could extend your has type to take two arguments and in the second argument it could store the value. This way you only iterate once.

Otherwise yes, reusing your code is a yes yes, just don't iterate two times when you could easily done it once.